# How to validate a form not to accept 'http' or 'https' in message body?

Tags: python, regex, django, validation

I tried to use regexvalidators from django to validate form so that it does not contain http or https (many spammers using link) but it doesn't work.

```
from django import forms
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from antispam.honeypot.forms import HoneypotField

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=11)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, validators=[RegexValidator(regex=r'http(s)?|HTTP(s)?', message="I don't accept link", code="invalid")])
    spam_honeypot_field = HoneypotField()
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

[This expression](https://regex101.com/r/BC0WmX/1) might help you to do so:

```
^((?!http|https).)+$
```

[image]

[image]

Based on [Pushpesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2102956/pushpesh-kumar-rajwanshi)'s advice, you can use a [much simplified expression](https://regex101.com/r/BC0WmX/2) using a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!.*\bhttps?\b).+$
```

which this graph shows how it would work:

[image]

#### Code

```
import re

string = 'Anything else that you wish except http://someurl.org'
# string = 'Anything else that you wish'
matches = re.search(r'^(((?!http|https).)+)$', string)
if matches:
    print(matches.group(1)+ " is a match")
else: 
    print('Sorry! No matches! Something is not right! Call 911!')
```

#### Output

```
Sorry! No matches! Something is not right! Call 911!
```

Comment: can I ask why the 3rd line is not matching with your regex?

Comment: cool... +1 from me :)